# Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'where' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type 'string[]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ionic-framework

I have the following javascript condition.

```js
var year = '2020'
var month = '05'
//var status = 'pending'

var dateParam = '' + year + '-' + month + '%';

if (status == 'pending' || status == 'completed')
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM activities AS a WHERE DATE(a.start_datetime) LIKE ? AND status = ?;";
    var where = [
        dateParam,
        status
    ]
}
else {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM activities AS a WHERE DATE(a.start_datetime) LIKE ?;";
    var where = [
        dateParam
    ]
}

console.log(query)
console.log(where)
```

While it works fine on a code-snippet, I could not get the warning out of Angular/Ionic with the following error.

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable
>   'where' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type 'string[]'.

[image]

What would be the best way to resolve this issue? I tried to experiment by declaring

```
var where = any[] = []
```

However, did not work and I may have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var year = '2020'
var month = '05'
//var status = 'pending'

var dateParam = '' + year + '-' + month + '%';
var where: any[] = [];
if (status == 'pending' || status == 'completed')
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM activities AS a WHERE DATE(a.start_datetime) LIKE ? AND status = ?;";
    where = [
        dateParam,
        status
    ]
}
else {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM activities AS a WHERE DATE(a.start_datetime) LIKE ?;";
    where = [
        dateParam
    ]
}

console.log(query)
console.log(where)
```

Just answer based on your code, declare and initialize `where` variable on the top.

because var has not block scope. and then `query` variable. too.

Comment: ah! this works! thanks for pointing to me what I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `var`, use `const`. `var` makes it a global variable.

Comment: It seems it won't work; Cannot find name 'where'.ts(2304)

Comment: You need to put your console.log statements in the same scope as the `where` and `query` variables. This is because they are not global anymore.